# Current research problems in Lattice based Crypto

Tags: lattice-crypto

I am looking for research problems in lattice based Crypto. Can anybody help?

Comment: If you have some specifiec directions, I believe you won't even be needing help. But since you don't have any direction, this post won't be too helpful to others either, which means this question would get closed.

Comment: Can you please tell me the names of different directions in this area?

Comment: e.g. Lattice Reduction Algorithms and Records, Hardness Assumptions such as LWE and LWR, and their Modular and Ring Variants, LPR-Style Encryption vs Key Exchange, GLP vs GPV Style Signature Scheme, NTRU Lattice, etc.

Comment: Chris Piekert recently [posed some interesting questions](https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/g/pqc-forum/c/SJVZFWos-TU) on the [NIST PQC forum list](https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/g/pqc-forum).